# What is the "Site graduation"?

Tags: support, badges

I've found in the description to the badge *Constable* term "...*or through site graduation*". So what does *Site graduation* mean?

Comment: I believe, and am not 100% hence the comment, that is when a site has moved from public beta to a full site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Site graduation is the final stage of the process in long process of becoming a "full" site on the network.

New sites are proposed on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). After progressing through Define, Commitment, Private Beta, Public Beta, the last step is to Graduate and become a full site.

With graduation, the site has moderator elections and receives a unique design to fit the theme of the site.*

---

*Graduation can occur [prior to receiving the design](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/congratulations-youre-about-to-graduate-with-a-twist), but it is uncommon at this point.

Answer (score 4):

Site graduation refers to a site moving from Area 51's last stage (public beta) to being a "full" site. (As @Kendra notes in the comment).

Comment: Okay, I got. So it is not reachable for *StackOverflow* anymore :)

Comment: @Yurets ...nor at all. Stack Overflow was never a part of Area 51 to my knowledge.

Comment: @Anonymous, oh, I didn't know that. Thanks :)